# media query not working in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var win = window;
var docElement = document.documentElement;
var logo = document.getElementById('topLine');
var myName = document.querySelector('.myLogo');
var listItems = document.getElementById('navi').getElementsByTagName('li');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#link');
var navTable = document.getElementById('navi');
var pngIcon = document.getElementById('icon');

 win.onscroll = function() {

  var sTop = (this.pageYOffset || docElement.scrollTop) - (docElement.clientTop || 0);

  if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 880px)").matches) {

   if(sTop > 0) {
     logo.style.backgroundColor = '#8b9dc3';
     logo.style.height = 70 + 'px';
     myName.style.fontSize = 40 + 'px';
     for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      listItems[i].style.fontSize = 25 + 'px';
     } 
     navTable.style.top = 70 + 'px';
     navTable.style.backgroundColor = '#8b9dc3';
     pngIcon.style.top = 15 + 'px';
   } else {
     logo.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(207, 212, 206, .4)';
     logo.style.height = 90 + 'px';
     myName.style.fontSize = 50 + 'px';
     for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      listItems[i].style.fontSize = 30 + 'px';
     }
     navTable.style.top = 90 + 'px';
     navTable.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(207, 212, 206, .4)';
     pngIcon.style.top = 24 + 'px';
   }
  } else {

   if(sTop > 0) {
     logo.style.backgroundColor = '#8b9dc3';
     logo.style.height = 70 + 'px';
     myName.style.fontSize = 40 + 'px';
     for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      listItems[i].style.fontSize = 25 + 'px';
     }
   } else {
     logo.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(207, 212, 206, .4)';
     logo.style.height = 90 + 'px';
     myName.style.fontSize = 50 + 'px';
     for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      listItems[i].style.fontSize = 30 + 'px';
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

```css
@media(max-width: 880px) {
 #navi {
  display: none;
 }
 .navWrapper label[for="mygtukas"] {
  background: url(images/open.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  top: 24px;
  filter: invert(85%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
 }
 .navWrapper input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #navi {
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
 <nav id="topLine">
  <div class="navWrapper" >
   <h1 class="myLogo"><span class="initial">E.</span><span class="name">Erlandas</span> Petronis</h1>
   <div class="shadow"></div>
   <label for="mygtukas" id="icon"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="mygtukas">
   <ul id="navi" class="hide">
    <li id="li"><a id="link" class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="li"><a id="link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

What I am trying to do is, on certain screen size to fire one js styling and on other to fire other, but seems media query is being ignored and I get double background - second one from drop down menu which is `display: none` in css.

This how it looks: I cant get rid of that background on top of the navbar when screen is full size.

[image]

The end result is on full screen when u scroll it changes style of navbar, it works all fine, just i get that color on top of my background when on full screen, and when screen is smaller than 880px than it changes to drop down menu and again changes style on scroll. 
Thank you in advance, hope i provided enough info.

Comment: You might find it easier to have a CSS class with the style changes and then simply change the class when scroll is active rather than changing all the style properties within the javascript. It will then keep all the styles in one place so it will be easier for you to find the issue

Comment: thank you for your tip, Friendly Code!! Its working now :D

Comment: Glad to hear it :)